# How can i find rows in DataTables according to row value

Tags: c#, select, datatable, row

I've got a DataTable in which there could be values in a column which looks like `x:1` `x:2` `a:1` `a:2` etc...  but they could also look like `x*` or `a*`.

In my code I'm getting a full value to search for (for example `x:1`), but the row itself can contain a value like `x*` in that column. 
can i somehow use the Select method to search for the row?

for now it looks something like this:

```
strSelect = string.Format("[{0}]='{1}'", colName, ValueToSearch);
rows = tempTable.Select(strSelect);
```

but of course that like that the only rows I'll get are those that look EXACTLY like the one in the table. meaning that when searching for `x:1`, i won't get the row with `x*`

Comment: Could you be a little clearer about what the value you're being given looks like, what the values in the database look like, and what you're expecting to be able to retrieve? The "x*" and "x:1" look like made-up examples, and are slightly complicating things because I'm not sure what your actual data looks like. Could you give a couple of real examples of what you're using to search with, what values are in the database, and what you expect a query to actually be looking for?

Comment: @Chris they are made up example but they do look kinda similar to the real values. an example for a real value can be: "G: ch1 - 2412" and there are a lot like it meaning with ch1 ch2 etc. and there could be similar values like it with "A: ch ... " or with B etc. now, i've got a table in which someone could right a specific real value, or it can also be "A: ch*" or "G*" since from the outside the value writer think of '*' as "any string", and i'm looking for a way to identify it easily

Answer (score 1):

The code `strSelect = string.Format("[{0}]='{1}'", colName, ValueToSearch);` will select the same values. If you want search for subset you must use LIKE operator:

```
strSelect = string.Format("[{0}] LIKE '{1}'", colName, ValueToSearch.Replace("*", "%");
```

Comment: what exactly does the replacement of "*" with "%" do?

Comment: this is also not correct since i wrote that the value i get to search is a full value meaning "x:1". The table itself may contain "x*" but what I'm receiving is the full value to search

Comment: If you don't specify the "*" then the LIKE operator works same as the "=" operator. Or I misunderstood your question.

Comment: in my situation, the data table can contain a value like x*. i am given a value of x:1 and i want to get the x* line. in your answer you answered like I'm searching for the x* but its the other way around

Comment: So, the input data "x:1" means "x:1" OR "x*" ?

Comment: the DATA TABLE is the one which can contains x:1 OR x*. BUT the value to search in the data table will ALWAYS be in the form of x:1. That means that if the table has x* in a column then its not true that x* is like x:1. (the opposite is true - x:1 is like x*)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming for the moment that your database includes 4 rows, with the following values in a given column that you're wanting to query against:

- x:1
- x:2
- x*
- a:1
- a:2
- a*

You state that you're being handed a value such as 'x:1' which you need to use in your query, but you're implying that the query should end up return the first three records - those with values of 'x:1', 'x:2', and 'x*'. In other words, although you're being handed 'x:1', you're actually want to search for any records that have a value that begins with 'x'.

If that's the scenario, you're probably best off modifying the value in your C# code before issuing the query. If your search value is genuinely of the form 'x:1', you could just chop off the last two characters before handing it to the SQL query:

```
string searchValue = "x:1"; // this presumably actually comes from user input
searchValue = searchValue.Substring(0, searchValue.Length - 2);
// Now searchValue is just "x", so go ahead and create your SQL query using the 'LIKE' operator
```

I have the feeling this is just a simplification of your actual data though, which makes it hard to be precise & also makes it harder to provide an example that includes error-checking.

For a slightly more complex example, perhaps the search-value your user gives you can either be a string of letters, or a string of letters followed by a colon followed by more letters. In that case, you need to check whether the string you've been given contains a colon, and if it does you need to chop off the colon and anything following it:

```
string searchValue = "abc:def";
if (searchValue.Contains(":"))
    searchValue = searchValue.Substring(0, searchValue.IndexOf(":"));
// Having stripped off ":def", you're left with "abc"
```

Now you can go ahead and issue a query, using the LIKE operator, as TcKs already showed in his answer. For example you could modify the query code you already have as follows:

```
strSelect = string.Format("[{0}] LIKE '{1}'", colName, ValueToSearch);
rows = tempTable.Select(strSelect);
```

By using the LIKE operator, you're now looking for any records that have a value which *starts* with "abc".

Comment: just to make it more clear - I am given a value which i read from somewhere which is ALWAYS the full one meaning its always in the form of "x:1". BUT, the table itself can have values like "x*" and the table has more rows and when you get a value of x:1 which fits to x*, something needs to be done according to another column in the table. Also, i can know for a fact that the same value in the table won't repeat itself in the same column. meaning i can have x:1 or x:2 in the same column but not x:1 and x*

Comment: i think you misunderstood what i asked in the question. The data table indeed contains like you wrote the values you wrote from the start BUT the value itself to search will ALWAYS be in its full form meaning for example x:1, which means that i can't use the LIKE operator since x:1 is not LIKE x* but rather the opposite. i want to get the row in which there could be x* with the value to search of x:1

Comment: That's why I said you need to chop off the 'end' piece. Don't search for x:1 at all, chop off the :1 and do a LIKE-based query on x. There's no magic way to hand SQL a query with x:1 as a search parameter and have it just know you want x* to be returned as well. If you're only wanting to search based on the first 'half' of a string, you need to do just that - get hold of the half you're interested in and use that as your parameter.

Comment: do you know of a way to check if the value in the table contains the string "*"? i don't know how to make an sql statement with conditions, meaning i want to compare the entire string of the value to search to the value in the column if there is no "*" in the column and i want to chop off the whatever is before the "*" if there is actually that string