# C# regex match behaviour

Tags: c#, regex, match

I've got this line in my code:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(actualValue, regexValue, RegexOptions.None);
```

I've got a simple question. why when checking for success meaning with the line:

```
if(match.Success)
```

then the match does succeed with the following values:

actualValue = `"G:1"`

regexValue = `"A*"`

the actual does not seem to fit at least for me so i probably miss something...

what i do want to achieve is just receiving an actual value and a regular expression and check if the actual value fits the regular expression.. i thought that's what i did there but apparently i didn't.

EDIT: another question. is there a way to treat the * as the "any char" wildcard? meaning is it possible that A* will be considered as A and after it any char is possible?

Comment: Look at RegexBuddy app. I find it very useful to create\test\re-use regex expression. _I am not associated with the company that sells this product._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code itself is correct; your regular expression isn't.

Based on your comments on other answers, you're after a regular expression which matches any string which starts with A, and you're assuming that '`*`' means "any characters". '`*`' in fact means "match the preceding character zero or more times", so the regular expression you've given means "match the start of the string followed by zero or more 'A' characters", which will match absolutely anything.

If you're looking for a regular expression that matches the whole string but only if it starts with 'A', the regular expression you're after is `^A.*`. The '`.`' character in a regular expression means "match any character". This regular expression thus means "match the start of the string, followed by an 'A', followed by zero or more other characters" and will thus match the entire string provided it starts with 'A'.

However, you already *have* the whole string, so this is a little unnecessary - all you really want to do is get an answer to the question "does the string start with an 'A'?". A regular expression that will achieve this is simply '^A'. If it matches, the string started with an 'A'.

Of course, it should be pointed out that you don't need a regular expression to confirm this anyway. If this is genuinely all you want to do (and it's possible you've just put together a simple example, and your real scenario is more complicated), why not just use the StartsWith method?:

```
bool match = actualValue.StartsWith("A");
```

Comment: Why not dump the /.*/ and stick to /^A/? /.*/ is a tautology as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Oday Mansour what does every symbol in /^A/?/.*/ means? i just understand the dot '.' means anything so why not just "A." as a reg expression?

Comment: "^A"  is what I'm proposing. I said that ".*" is a tautology because it will fit anything. "." means "any character" and "\*" means "0 or more times" so ".*" means "anything 0 or more times". "^A" means "A string that starts (^) with A (A)". The "?" here was for the question, not the regex. Also as a side note, some people are used to write regex patterns between / slashes so /^A/ is basically the regex pattern "^A".

Comment: @OdayMansour and you don't have to add the dot somewhere like ^A. ? and btw how can i check is something finishes with a certain string? for example i want to find anything which ends with "abc"

Comment: @OdayMansour You're correct, /^A.*/ is unnecessary and /^A/ will do. If the user wants the whole string, well, they already have it - all they need to do is check whether it starts with an 'A'. Now that I'm more awake, though, it also occurs to me that a regular expression is completely unnecessary for this case anyway - just calling actualValue.StartsWith("A") is simpler, reads more clearly, and may possibly even be more efficient than firing up the regular-expression engine. I've edited my answer appropriately.

Comment: @Yonaton If all you're wanting to do is check whether a string starts or ends with a particular string, there's no need to use regular expressions at all. The string class already has StartsWith and EndsWith methods anyway, for example bool match = actualValue.StartsWith("A");

Comment: @OdayMansour can you check out my question here to see what i really am trying to accomplish and if you've got an answer ill be glad to receive it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757599/how-can-i-find-rows-in-datatables-according-to-row-value/11758091#comment15617990_11758091

Comment: @Chris the above comment was meant for you as well :)

Answer (score 1):

The regex matches because `A*` means "look for *0* or more occurrences of 'A'". It will match any string.

If you meant to look for an arbitrary number of 'A', but at least one, try `A+` instead.

Comment: so how can i match only strings which begin with "A" and can have anything after? is it A+?

Comment: @YonatanNir You'll have to specify to match at the beginning of the string using the caret (`^`), like so: `^A+`

Comment: If you want the string to start with an A, the correct regex is /^A/

Comment: @OdayMansour You're right, I might have misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the comments it looks like you're trying to match a lot of strings starting with A. 
If they're separated by white space you could find all of them using the following:

```
bool matched = Regex.IsMatch(actualValue, @"\bA\w+");
```

This matches : "Atest flkjs Apple Ascii cAse".

If there is only one string you're matching and it starts with A and has no spaces:

```
bool matched = Regex.IsMatch(actualValue, @"^A\w+$");
```

This matches "Apple", but not "Apple and orange" as the second string has spaces.

As Chris noted * is not a wildcard in the way you meant with regex searches. You can find some information to get you started with regexes at [regex-info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html).

Comment: it sounds like that the first option is better for me. just what does the \b and \w+ means?

Comment: \b is "word boundary" which would mean the start of a word in this case as it's on the left side of the regex.
\w+ means "match one or more word characters (letters, numbers, underscore)".

Answer (score 0):

Regex take the regular expression in the constructor.
Exampel in your case could be :

```
if(new Regex("A*").IsMatch(actualValue)
   //Do something
```

If you are unsecure of the regexpattern, try it out [here](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: is there a way to use the * as wildcard of "any char"? meaning the A* will search for A and then anything which come after?

Comment: You can try this one.For the problem where string starts with "A" and could be anything "A\w+" is a good match.

"\w" = word character [A-Za-z0-9_]

"+" = One or more of the preceding element